# Memcached clustering with zero downtime

Tags: memcached, multi-tenant, saas, failover, microsoft-distributed-file-system

I am having problems in applying memcached clustering in my multi-tenant system. Actually I have applied memcached as my first phase of project - the result is my system is has been supported by two tomcat instances, if one fails second tomcat carries out the responsibility and memcache node provides the session replication.

But now I have to make sure that I can apply patches to my project without the downtime of tomcat. How can I achieve the same? Do I have to implement `glusterFS DFS`?